# Printing a Python Program for coordinates

Tags: python, string, xcode, printing

I am working on a python program which requires me to take a series of points (listed below). My program needs to be able to read the text file and print the coordinates to the screen as follows:

here is the format ive been using

point list:

```
p1:4,13
p2:13,11
p3:0,8
p4:3,0
```

my program so far

```
>>> coordinates = open('students.txt', 'r') 
>>> lines = coordinates.readlines() 
>>> lines 
['place,coordiantes\n', 'p1,4,13\n', 'p2,13,11\n', 'p3,0,8    \n','p4,3,0']
>>> for line in lines: 
...     print line.strip().split(',') 
['place', 'coordinate'] ['p1', '4,13'] ['p2', '13,11'] ['p3', '0,8']['p4','3,0']
```

my problem is I need to remove the `,` between the place and coordinate on the final print. Any suggestions to help with this?

Comment: But if they are two elements of the same sublist, they will be printed with a comma in between. You can use `for line in lines:  for l in line.strip().split(','): print (l)`. I am not sure how you exactly want them to be printed

Comment: @Veridian When running your code, I get the everything splittet correctly, just as you want it. Are you sure that you are showing us the correct code and output you got?

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = ['place,coordiantes\n', 'p1,4,13\n', 'p2,13,11\n', 'p3,0,8    \n','p4,3,0']


lines = [stuff.replace("\n", "") for stuff in lines]
lines = [stuff.replace(" ", "") for stuff in lines]


points = {}

new_list = []
for line in lines:
    new_list.append(line.split(","))

for line in new_list:

    if len(line) > 2:
        print(line[0] + ": " + line[1] + "," + line[2])
```

Gives:

```
p1: 4,13
p2: 13,11
p3: 0,8
p4: 3,0
```

Is this what you want?